# Was bedeutet "etwas liegt ab"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Ich habe eine Excel-Tabelle aus einer Übernahme, die wahrscheinlich von einem Deutschen erstellt wurde. Alles ist auf Englisch, bis auf eine Spalte, in der für einige Positionen der Hinweis "die Daten liegen ab" oder "etwas liegt ab" steht. Das hat zwar keinen großen Wert, aber ich bin neugierig, was es bedeutet.

Bedeutet das, dass die Daten irgendwo abgelegt sind, oder dass sie noch ausstehen?

Comment: Das ist kein Standarddeutsch sondern Dialekt oder Jargon.

Comment: Ich fürchte, ohne weiteren Kontext wird sich das nicht klären lassen. Überlicherweise bedeutet "abliegen", dass sich etwas durch das liegen verändert, z.B. eine Fermentierung oder Reifung stattfindet, manchmal auch im Übertragenen Sinne, - etw. ist "gut abgelegen", wenn es sehr lange ignoriert wurde. Das scheint aber hier nicht ganz zu passen. (siehe Bedeutung 2 von [Duden: abliegen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/abliegen))

Comment: Die Bedeutung 1 - weit entfernt sein - könnte in einem Jargon plausibel sein, habe ich allerdings noch nie in Zusammenhang mit Daten gehört.

Comment: Ohne Kontext kann man hier wirklich nur spekulieren. Wenn nach "etwas liegt ab" noch etwas folgt, könnte eine Position gemeint sein, etwa "die Daten liegen ab Zeile 365" oder "die Bauteile liegen ab Regal 3". Oder es ist ein simpler Tippfehler und sollte eigentlich "die Daten liegen an" (im Sinne einer Anlage oder Beilage zu einem Schreiben) heißen, und der Fehler wurde dann einfach immer wieder kopiert.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Im IT-Jargon oder allgemeiner im Büro-Jargon bedeutet "Die Daten liegen ab", dass die Daten für andere zugänglich abgelegt sind und bei Bedarf abgerufen bzw. heruntergeladen werden können. Genauer gesagt sind damit meist Dateien/Files gemeint.

*Aktion:* Jemand legt die Daten ab.
*Ergebnis:* Die Daten liegen ab.

Schlimme Logik, aber so wird es benutzt.

Vor allem im Zusammenhang mit Datei*ablagen* (file shares) auf Servern ist das ein sehr üblicher Begriff.

> Liebe Kollegen, der Besucherreport für Juli liegt ab sofort im Ordner \reports\2021\ ab.

Formulierungen, die diesen Jargon vermeiden, wären:

> Der Besucherreport ... ist unter ... abgelegt.
> Der Besucherreport ... steht unter ... zum Download bereit.
> Der Besucherreport ... steht unter ... zur Verfügung.

Oder man lässt einfach das überflüssige "ab" weg:

> Der Besucherreport ... liegt im Ordner ... .

Ein paar Fundstellen für den Gebrauch von "abliegen" als IT-Jargon in diesem Sinn:

https://www.commhaconsulting.com/2015/03/unternehmenswiki/
("Sätze wie „Diese Info müsste irgendwo auf dem Server abliegen“ oder „Hatten wir dazu nicht mal was erarbeitet?“ sind in Ihrem Unternehmen sicherlich auch schon gefallen. Seit mehr als einem Jahr ist bei uns Schluss mit der Sucherei ...")

https://answers.microsoft.com/de-de/msoffice/forum/all/ms-project-2013-verkn%C3%BCpfung-zu-unterprojekten/a6f21508-d253-48c9-85e8-4ef9f7b9d7f6
("Hallo zusammen, ich habe eine MS Project 2010 Datei, welche auf einer "Site" in SharePoint Server 2013 abliegt. In dieser Project-Datei möchte ich nun gerne Verknüpfungen zu Unter-Projekten einfügen, welche ebenfalls in dieser Sharepoint-Site abliegen.")

https://administrator.de/forum/gibt-es-etwas-%C3%A4hnliches-wie-einen-papierkorb-f%C3%BCr-den-server-127530.html
("Klar, da[ss] die "gelöschten" Daten irgendwo abliegen müssen und das[s] dafür zusätzlicher Plattenspeicher benötigt wird. Aber grundsätzlich kann man eh nie genug Plattenspeicher haben.")

Comment: Interessant, hab ich noch nie gehört - bisher immer nur "Die Daten sind (am Fileshare/im Verzeichnis) abgelegt"

Comment: Ergänzungsvorschlag: Eine einwandfreie Formulierung wäre "Der Besucherreport ... ist unter ... abgelegt".

Comment: @guidot: gute Idee, danke.